# How to select only visible rows when working with autofilters

Tags: excel, vba

I Have recently written some code that takes the date and time of the last five times an event has ocurred and Pastes it to a running data table that i have on another worksheet.

I am trying to use the autofilter method to help me single out the results that I want to paste. As you can see from the code below after I apply the filter I tell VBA to find the last row and then offset -4 rows and then select the active row and everything underneath it. However it considers the hidden rows as well.

Is there any way i can get excel to offset -4 rows using only the rows that were a result of my filter? I tried using the SpecialCells method, however it just selects every visible row in my table which is not what i want. All I want is for VBA to be able to offset rows considering rows that are in line with my filter.

```
 'Update Cidade de Marica
Worksheets("Raw Data").Columns("E").AutoFilter 5, "Cidade de Marica"

ActiveSheet.Range("$K$3").Activate
ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(, 10).Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(-4, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Activate
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
```

Comment: You can edit your question and add some screenshots of your data and the expected results

Answer (score 0):

First of all - do not use .Activate and .Select methods in your code, unless you do need to activate or select the cell/range. For example, the code like:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(1,1).Select
Selection.Activate
Selection.Copy 
Selection.Offset(1,0).Select
Selection.Paste
```

can be replaced with this:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(1,1).Copy Destination:= Selection.Offset(1,0)
```

It means that you don't have to select or activate cells to do something with it.

**Update**

As appeared from comments by @chrisneilsen, I misunderstood the basic task, so here is the solution:

```
Dim r As range
Dim i As Long, j As Integer

With Worksheets("Raw Data")
    .Columns(5).AutoFilter 5, "Cidade de Marica" 'apply filter as needed
    For i = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row To 1 Step -1    'going from last filled cell up
        If Not .Rows(i).Hidden Then                             'if the row is visible
            If r Is Nothing Then                                'adding this row to range
                Set r = .Rows(i)
                j = j + 1
            Else
                Set r = Union(r, .Rows(i))
                j = j + 1
            End If
        End If

        If j = 5 Then Exit For 'you may change this condition - now it looks only for 5 rows

    Next

    r.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:="where_do_you_need_to_copy_it"  'and copy (do not select or activate) those cells from range to another location
End With
```

Also, try to avoid using ActiveCell and ActiveSheet - these things may change surprisingly and VBA doesn't care that you or someone else occasionally change an active sheet or active cell.

Comment: @chrisneilsen Chris, thanks for pointing out that thing! But actually, I wasn't going to give a ready solution for OP, and showed him the way to copy like he wants, as you see in code comments - I've mentioned that he should put there his own range. Nevertheless, I've edited an answer to put last 5 rows to my `r` range.

Comment: @chrisneilsen thanks again, I misunderstand the task. Now it should work properly.